# Getting & error(unnatural functionality ) while search a text from page in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching a text from page. Every thing is fine. But there is only one problem that when user search for **&** it search but also append the data with **amp**. Can you please tell me why it occurring?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/wjLmx/22/

Please enter & , then click search and again click search,search, next find the issue.

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "#realTimeContents"; //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted'); //Remove old search highlights  

            //Remove the previous matches
            $span = $('#realTimeContents span');
            $span.replaceWith($span.html());

            $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');

            var i=0;

            $('.next_h').off('click').on('click', function () {
                i++;

                if(i >= $('.match').length)
                    i=0;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');                
            });
            $('.previous_h').off('click').on('click', function () {

                i--;

                if(i < 0)
                    i=$('.match').length-1;

                    $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                    $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
            });




            if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.searchButtonClickText_h', function (event) {

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
    if (!searchAndHighlight($('.textSearchvalue_h').val())) {
        alert("No results found");
    }


});
```

Comment: *"unnatural functionality"*?!

Comment: actually i never seen  this bug

Comment: You're switching between `.html()` and `.text()`. Why?

Comment: I need to search that the text that why..?

Comment: i understand the issue .But problem in solving .I am trying my best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, to get the character `&`, you use a character entity: `&amp;`. So when searching HTML text, you're bound to find those (you may also find `&lt;` and `&nbsp;` and other character entities). Your code is taking this HTML:

```
&amp;
```

...and changing it to:

```
<span class="match highlighted">&</span>amp;
```

...and so you're seeing the `amp;` in the text.

This is a specific example of a general problem with that code. Unfortunately, I think the approach that code takes will be too complicated to correct. I think in order to solve this entire class of problems, you have to not do the replacements in the HTML at all. Instead, loop through the [text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) in the matching element and do the replacements on their `nodeValue`s, which will be normal strings (containing just `&` and the like), not HTML-encoded entities. You'll have to use [`splitText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-38853C1D) to split the text node (twice, before and after the text you're replacing), and then put the middle bit inside a `span` you create via [`createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547), inserting the `span` in front of the second split point.

That would be the general solution: Don't try to do `replace` on the HTML.

Now, you can solve this **specific** bug quite easily, by putting this before the line doing the replacement on the HTML: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/23/)

```
if (searchTerm === "&") {
    searchTerm = "&amp;";
    searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
}
```

...but that won't solve the general problem. Solving the general problem probably requires completely changing your approach, using text nodes and such as described earlier.

---

Side note: You're passing the user's search term directly into the `RegExp` constructor. Do you really expect your users to correctly type regular expressions? If they type `[`, for instance, the result will be an invalid regex. If you want to search literally for what they type, you'll have to either not use a regex, or escape special characters in the regex.

Comment: can you please change on my fiddle?

Comment: @Rohit: It's up to you to correct the code. I'm just answering the question of what's wrong with it. Now that you know that, you can presumably fix it.

Comment: how to remove this ..? is there any way to remove this..?

Comment: @Rohit: I'm sure there is.

Comment: @Rohit: Again: It's up to you to write the code. Stack Overflow is for helping people understand things, it's not a code-writing service. I hope I've helped you understand what the problem with your code is: You're splitting up character entities. So don't do that. Detect that you're splitting up a character entity and keep it together.

Comment: From the last two days i am working on search functionality now this bug come .can you help me on solving this.

Comment: @Rohit: I've added a bit to the answer to show you how to solve *this specific bug*. But it's just one example of a class of issues you're going to have to address. If you want to outsource solving this problem, my firm's rates are reasonable. :-)

Comment: @Rohit: ...and I've added even more to point you at how to solve this generally. Good luck with it,